# Meteor local server can access database but client can't

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm new to meteor. So I want to access data from my local database in mongodb. I have client.js in client folder

```
Meteor.subscribe('Signal');
console.log(Data.find().fetch());
```

And my server directory has main.js having

```
console.log(Data.find());

Meteor.publish('Signal', function() {
   return Data.find().fetch();
});
```

Server's console.log shows result in the terminal but the client doesn't show anything the chrome's console

Under lib/ I have collectons.js it contains

```
Data = new Mongo.Collection('data');
```

I have checked my mongodb from shell and the collection data is present with needed data. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forgetting that `Meteor.subscribe()` on client is not *immediate* action, and publication will take its time to populate documents to client.

Fortunately, [`Meteor.subscribe()` returns a subscription handle](https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Meteor-subscribe), that can be used to determine subscription readiness.

```js
const handle = Meteor.subscribe('Signal');
Tracker.autorun(() => {
  if (handle.ready()) {
    // subscription is ready
    console.log(Data.find().fetch());
  }
});
```

Alternatively, you can pass your `onReady` callback as the last argument to `Meteor.subscribe()`:

```js
Meteor.subscribe('Signal', () => {
  // subscription is ready
  console.log(Data.find().fetch());
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution. Actually I fixed it using `iron:router`. But this seems much better as I don't have to install any additional package. what's your opinion? is it better with package or inbuilt functions? Thanks

Comment: @Khacho `iron:router` just doing something similar under the hood. Actually, that's depend on how do you use this data later. If you're using it in template helpers — you don't even need this code, they (helpers) are reactive already and they will be re-run after your subscription will fetch data.